# Azure Table Storage duration before being able to retrieve data

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm inserting like 6000 values into a Azure table storage. I'm inserting the values, 100 a time, in [TableBatchOperations](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet#insert-a-batch-of-entities). Values are inserted in a async method which is awaited.

Now many of my integration tests fail. They're trying to retrieve previously inserted values, but instead of the 6K values, only 1K or 2K values are returned. If I insert a Task.Delay of multiple seconds in my test, it succeeds.

So `table.ExecuteBatchAsync()` runs to completion for all of my 60 batches. Does anybody know why there's still so much time between the (completed) insertion and being able to retrieve the data?

*Note: you can reproduce this behavior with Microsoft Azure Table Explorer. During insertion, hit the refresh button for the table.*

*Note2: I've searched a lot for this phenomenon, can't really find any specs of Microsoft stating the time between insertion and being able to retrieve data. I also couldn't find any similar posts on Stackoverflow.*

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what's going on, but not sure I'd call it a *phenomenon*. Table Storage, and storage accounts in general, have well-documented throughput and performance targets, and no SLA on those targets, so it's entirely possible that you are exceeding throughput limits, and that it takes a while to write your content.

Comment: What's the API you're using to retrieve the inserted entities? Maybe the service just returned a segmented result and you need to retrieve again with the continuation token in previous segment.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft I'm using the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` nuget-package. I'm reading +1000 entities using a do-while loop and the continuation token, just like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet#retrieve-entities-in-pages-asynchronously). Eventually all data is returned, it's just about the time between inserting and being able to retrieve all data.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thank you for your comment. I did search a bit more and found the performance and scalability checklist ([Checklist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-performance-checklist)). One of the items is about unbounded Parallelism. I'm doing a parallel insert. So maybe i'm getting trottled because of the parallelism. I'll look into it and keep this thread updated.